# selecting uniques out of table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i have a mysql db table as follows

```
      date                  id                   name 

   2012-09-18               1                     A
   2012-09-18               2                     B
   2012-09-18               1                     C
   2012-09-17               1                     D
   2012-09-17               1                     A
   2012-09-17               2                     A
   2012-09-16               1                     A
   2012-09-16               1                     E
```

DESIRED RESULT FOR ID = 1

```
     DATE                  UNIQUES
   2012-09-18               1      
   2012-09-17               1  
   2012-09-16               2
```

DESCRIPTION IN WORDS

I want to count unique names per id grouped by date .
eg.
for 16 sep. uniques =2  because A , E   do not occur before 16 sep in this table .
for 17 sep. uniques =1  because D does not occur before 17 sep in this table and A has already occurred on 16 sep.

Comment: So, you want to boil your list down to the first date for each name, and then count names by date

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(question) FROM your.questions WHERE accepted = 1` returns too little to expect a decent answer, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
SELECT `date`,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN so_far = 1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end) AS UNIQUES
FROM   (SELECT a.`date`,
               a.id,
               a.name,
               Count(DISTINCT b.`date`) AS so_far
        FROM   srctable AS a
               JOIN srctable AS b
                 ON ( a.id = b.id
                      AND a.name = b.name
                      AND a.`date` >= b.`date` )
        GROUP  BY a.`date`,
                  a.id,
                  a.name) AS tab
WHERE  id=1
GROUP  BY `date`
```

As it's not correlated should be of a quite good performance.

**EDIT**

Motivated by the environment I've revised my query, and in fact there was a field for improvement.

```
SELECT a.`date` AS adt,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN b.`date` IS NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           end) AS unq
FROM   some_table AS a
       LEFT JOIN some_table AS b
              ON ( a.id = b.id
                   AND a.name = b.name
                   AND a.`date` > b.`date` )
WHERE  a.id = 1
GROUP  BY a.`date`,
          a.id;
```

In case in doubt you can check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e180a/2) and eventually compare with other proposed solutions.

Comment: @Nikhil I don't get it, first of all this query gives you wrong result, and second, never ever will this query be as fast as mine. Why did you accept it? Don't you get how this site works?

Comment: Yes , this query does not provides me with accurate results but by tweaking it a bit I was able to reach close to answer of my other question.
That's why i accepted the sol... i just forgot to mention it...next time i'll keep that in mind.. sorry folks...

Comment: @Nikhil That's fine, but not how upvotes or accepts should be used. Tooltip for upvote: "This post was **useful**" whereas an accept marks the answer that solves the question at hand. The way you use it is misleading for other newbies who might think that this answer is better than mine, but no offense WojtusJ, this query is crap. It's like you want to hammer in a nail with a toothbrush.

Comment: @Nikhil, please tell me the tweak, so I will correct my query.

Comment: @tombom, have you heard that crying guys are pathetic? :-) By the way -and also, no offence man - using correlation within subquery where it's not needed is a sign of beeing an amateur, also stating that IT IS BETTER suggests that you have absolutely no idea how database works. What's more, -1 by my answer looks like act of desperation, and also says you have no idea about SO rules. By the way, I am really sorry that YOUR answer wasn't accepted, but crying probably won't help. :-]

Comment: I can only laugh about your comment. Really, made my day.

Comment: I'm not desperately begging for reputation, it's about correct usage of SO, **and** I wouldn't even mention it if your query wasn't such a bullshit. And me being an amateur for using correlation is just facepalm, especially in comparison with your query. You, sir, have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Didn't check before, now I've corrected the query so it returns correct results (so I hope no other "disgusted expert" will have a reason to minus the answer ;-) ).

Comment: One downvote from me. If you, as you state, have the total idea how databases work, you should have seen that your query is fragile in results compared to tomboms more robust one. You sir should repeat your basic classes in database theory before you tell other that they have no understanding in how databases work. (Protip: non deterministic use of GROUP BY in your query.)

Comment: That's true, I've omitted one factor as I was proposing answer without checking. After revising with execution plan I've made some improvement - and happily got even better than @tombom 's. Btw. I'm not sure what those down votes are for... the only thing that comes to my mind is an irritation that the world is unfair - but it still has nothing to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
`date`,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM yourTable u2 WHERE u1.date > u2.date AND u1.name = u2.name) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS uniques
FROM
yourTable u1
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: +1, so you have something to show for your trouble, and for providing a better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (d date, id integer, name varchar(30));

insert into t (d, id, name) values
('2012-09-18', 1, 'A'),
('2012-09-18', 2, 'B'),
('2012-09-18', 1, 'C'),
('2012-09-17', 1, 'D'),
('2012-09-17', 1, 'A'),
('2012-09-17', 2, 'A'),
('2012-09-16', 1, 'A'),
('2012-09-16', 1, 'E')
;

select d as `DATE`, count(*) as UNIQUES
from (
    select name, min(d) as d
    from t
    where id = 1
    group by name
    ) s
group by `DATE`
order by `DATE` desc
;
+------------+---------+
| DATE       | UNIQUES |
+------------+---------+
| 2012-09-18 |       1 |
| 2012-09-17 |       1 |
| 2012-09-16 |       2 |
+------------+---------+
```